# A function that debits a virtual wallet and calls an API to disburse to a real account

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, promise

I am trying to determine if there is a better way to handle reversals for this function.

This is how it works:

A user inputs in amount, bank, and account number this would be used to debit his virtual wallet like so:

```
models.sequelize.transaction(function(t){
      Q.fcall(function(){
        console.log("this is amount: ",params.amount);
        var debit_wallet = models.wallet.findOne({
          attributes: ['id', 'balance'],
          transaction: t,
          lock: t.LOCK.UPDATE,
          where: {
            userId: req.session.passport.user,
            balance: {
              $gt: params.amount
            }
          }
        });

          return [debit_wallet, params];
      })
      .spread(function(debit_wallet, params){
        if (!debit_wallet) throw(new Error("insufficient balance"));

        originalBalance = debit_wallet.balance;

        debit_wallet.set('balance', parseFloat(debit_wallet.balance) - parseFloat(params.amount));

        var withdrawLog = models.withdrawal.build({
          userId: req.session.passport.user,
          //provider_ref: response.data.data.ref,
          account_number: params.accountNumber,
          bank_code: params.bankcode,
          amount: params.amount
        });

        return [ withdrawLog.save({transaction: t}), debit_wallet.save({transaction: t}), params];
      })
      .spread(function(withdrawLog, debit_wallet, params){
        var bankLog = models.bankaccount.findOrCreate({
          where: {
            'userId': req.session.passport.user,
            'bank_account': params.accountNumber,
            'bank_code': params.bankcode
          }
        });

        var walletLog = models.wallethistory.build({
          withdrawalId: withdrawLog.id,
          walletId: debit_wallet.id,
          payments_direction: 'debit',
          amount: params.amount
        });

        return [withdrawLog, debit_wallet, bankLog, walletLog.save({transaction: t}), params];
      })
      .spread(function(withdrawLog, debit_wallet, bankLog, walletLog, params){
        txd.resolve(withdrawLog);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log("Error Occurred: ", err);
        txd.reject(err);
      })
      return txd.promise;
    })
    .then(function(response){
      res.json({success: true, response: response});// A response is sent back for successful debit.
      d.resolve(response);
```

Only after that is the call to the external API made to actually send the money to the user's account, that call is made inside the `then` call of the transaction so as not to block/slowdown `db` operations.

Sample:

```
  .then(function(response){
      res.json({success: true, response: response});
      d.resolve(response);
     // Request is fired to external call
      request(requestObject).then(function(response){
     // Response is checked here if it fails I want to reverse the db action of `debit` that took place.
        if (response.data.data && response.data.data.responsecode == '00') {
          statusObject.payload = response.data.data.ref;
          request(statusObject).then(function(result){
            if (result.data.flutterResponseCode != '00' || result.data.flutterResponseCode != '0') {
          // I try to reverse debit here and update status
              Q.fcall(function(){
                var debitReversal = models.wallet.findOne({
                  attributes: ['id', 'balance'],
                  where: {
                    userId: req.session.passport.user,
                  }
                });

                var withdrawLog = models.withdrawal.findOne({
                  attributes: ['id','provider_status', 'provider_ref'],
                  where: {
                    'userId': req.session.passport.user
                  }
                });

                  return [debitReversal, withdrawLog];
              })
              .spread(function(debitReversal, withdrawLog){
                debitReversal.set('balance', parseFloat(debitReversal.balance) + parseFloat(params.amount));

                withdrawLog.set('provider_status', 'failed');
                withdrawLog.set('provider_ref', result.data.flutterReference);

                var walletLog = models.wallethistory.findOne({
                  where: {
                    'withdrawalId': withdrawLog.id
                  }
                });

                return [debitReversal.save(), withdrawLog.save(), walletLog];
              })
              .spread(function(debitReversal, withdrawLog, walletLog){
                walletLog.set('payment_state', 'failed');

                return [debitReversal, withdrawLog, walletLog.save()];
              })
              .spread(function(debitReversal, withdrawLog, walletLog){
                  txd.resolve(debitReversal);
              })
              .catch(function(err){
                console.log("Error ocurred: ", err);
                txd.reject(err);
              })
            } else {
              Q.fcall(function(){
                var withdrawLog = models.withdrawal.findOne({
                  attributes: ['id','provider_status', 'provider_ref'],
                  where: {
                    'userId': req.session.passport.user
                  }
                });

                return [withdrawLog];
              })
              .spread(function(withdrawLog){
                withdrawLog.set('provider_status', 'successful');
                withdrawLog.set('provider_ref', result.data.flutterReference);

                var walletLog = models.wallethistory.findOne({
                  where: {
                    'withdrawalId': withdrawLog.id
                  }
                });

                return [withdrawLog.save(), walletLog];
              })
              .spread(function(withdrawLog, walletLog){
                walletLog.set('payment_state', 'successful');

                return [withdrawLog, walletLog.save()];
              })
              .spread(function(withdrawLog, walletLog){
                txd.resolve(walletLog);
              })
              .catch(function(err){
                console.log("Error Occured: ", err);
                txd.reject(err);
              })
            }
          }) /* end of disburse status call */
          .catch(function(err){
            console.log("Error occured checking disburse status: ",err);
          })
        }
      }) /* end of disburse call*/
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log("Error occured disbursing: ", err);
      })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      res.json({success: false, response: err.message});
      d.reject(err);
    })
    return d.promise;

  }
```

What I am doing inside the `then` is checking if the call failed and reversing the debit on the virtual wallet.

I need help on review to know if:

1. I am following the right process for a reversal
2. How the code can be much cleaner
3. What areas I am employing bad practices